# Number of regular $n$-topes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: soft-question, polyhedra, platonic-solids, dimension-theory-analysis

Ever since I've come across it, I have been puzzled by the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}=(1,1,\infty,5,6,3,3,3,\cdots)$, describing the number of regular $n$-topes in $n$-dimensions, where $a(k)=3$ for $k\geq 5$.

E.g; $a(3)=5$, we have our familiar friends, the 5 platonic solids, etc.

I am curious, is there generalization of this for fractional dimensions? I understand that this is a quite is abstract question.

I.e;  what is the most canonical (or natural) function $f(n):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(n)=a_n$ when $a\in\mathbb{N}_0$? Of course, there are an uncountably infinite number of functions which would fulfill this, but perhaps there is one that encapsulates what it means to be a regular $n$-tope.

Perhaps a function which would look something like this?

[image]

Comment: I wrote my PhD thesis on polytopes and I dived rather deep into symmetric polytopes in particular, and I have never come across even the concept of a polytope in a fractional dimension. Usually, defining polytopes as convex hulls or as objects with "flat parts" requires a linear structure on a kind of ambient space and I am not aware of a nice concept of linear structure on a space with fractional dimension. However, I am no expert for the latter.

Comment: The  "Number of regular convex polytopes in n-dimensional space, or -1 if the number is infinite" is shown [here](https://oeis.org/A060296)